# Validate password with confirm password during sign up in php

Tags: php, validation, passwords, password-confirmation

We are using below code for "sign up". we have only **password** field , we want to add **confirm password** field.

**signup.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $uname = trim($_POST['txtuname']);
    $email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtpass']);
    $code = md5(uniqid(rand()));

    $stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $msg = "
              email allready exists 
              ";
    }
    else
    {
        if($reg_user->register($uname,$email,$upass,$code))
        {           
            $id = $reg_user->lasdID();      
            $key = base64_encode($id);
            $id = $key;

            $message = "                    
                        some message";

            $subject = "Confirm Registration";

            $reg_user->send_mail($email,$message,$subject); 
            $msg = "
                    some message
                    ";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "sorry , Query could no execute...";
        }       
    }
}
```

**class.usr.php**

```
public function register($uname,$email,$upass,$code)
    {
        try
        {                           
            $password = md5($upass);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userEmail,userPass,tokenCode) 
                                                         VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code)");
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
            $stmt->execute();   
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

I tried adding below code, but it did't worked for me.

```
$cpass = trim($_POST['txtpass']);
```

/* Afer if statement */

```
elseif($pass != $cpass){
             $msg = "passwords doesn't match";
        }
```

also tried in `class.usr.php` file, but no luck.....

Comment: You are using `trim($_POST['txtpass'])` for both `$pass` and `$cpass` value. Your `$cpass` should be different. Let assume you confirm password input field name is `confirm_password`. So. your `$cpass = trim($_POST['confirm_password'])`

Comment: @MahfuzulAlam Thanks for your support.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
First of all you have not mentioned confirm password field. 
Lets assume your confirm password field is "txtConfirmPass"

Before redirect to register function need to check password and confirm password like

$upass = trim($_POST['txtpass']);
$uConfirmPass = trim($_POST['txtConfirmPass']);

if($upass != $uConfirmPass){

    // Password not match your code here
}else{
    if($reg_user->register($uname,$email,$upass,$code)){           
        $id = $reg_user->lasdID();      
        $key = base64_encode($id);
        $id = $key;

        $message = "some message";

        $subject = "Confirm Registration";

        $reg_user->send_mail($email,$message,$subject); 
        $msg = "some message";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "sorry , Query could no execute...";
    }
}

Hopefully it help you out.
```

Comment: i am getting this error : `Notice: Undefined index: txtConfirmPass in line : `$uConfirmPass = trim($_POST['txtConfirmPass']);`

Comment: is i need to add any code in `class.usr.php` ? or is this problem of using 2 `else if` conditions ?

Comment: This "txtConfirmPass" field is for understanding in answer you need to set actual confirm password field in your HTML

Comment: looks like its working, id there nay code i need to add in `class.usr.php` ?